# Show Google Maps using Latitude and Longitude in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to mark the location of requesters of my website on google map.I successfully store longitude and latitude of Requester in DB but now I want to mark the location on google map, I used this code(Found it from a website) asp controls got red underlined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
                {
                    "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
            }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: no it doesn't compile

Comment: what does the top of your aspx look like?

Comment: I use <asp:content> then I used 2 scripts one is posted in question and other script is used just to show map on page,simple javascript.

Comment: Mine compiles fine using code from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Google-Maps-using-Latitude-and-Longitude-in-ASPNet.aspx . I have red squiggles under asp control. but it compiles. what error are you getting on compile?